# SharePoint 2013: "Find an Item" search is not returing all results. over 700 items in the list

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, search, custom-list

I have a custom SP list with over 750 items listed. When I try to search for ID# 100 for example, it will return the item. However, when I try to search for ID# 753 for example, it does not return any results. Any thoughts?

Things to note:

- The ID field is a default field in the custom list and is the unique identifier for each record
- Content Approval is turned off
- Data has been re-indexed
- I am the admin of the whole site and confirmed my permissions on the list

Comment: Are you searching for "753" or "listitemid=753"? Have you displayed the ID column in the view to confirm that there is an item with an ID of 753?

Comment: Can you share what you've attempted thus far?

Comment: Thanks for responding! I am just searching for the item ID# "753" or what ever number I need to search. I can search for everything up to ID# 737. Any number before that, even 736, returns the item. If is search any number after 736 no records appear but I know they exist because they are in the filter dropdown.

Comment: Also to note, the items I am trying to search from were created 2 days ago.

Comment: When you look in the crawl logs do you see the item 753?

Comment: How are you searching?  Using the Search field for the list or using some other search like a Power Automate action or REST call?  

If you are using the List Search, are you using the Classic or Modern interface?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the item is real existing via filtering view by “753”.

Access crawl log to see if the item is crawled successfully via searching item URL.
[image]

Search this item in site search box, check if you can get the correct result.

Comment: Where do I access the Crawl Logs to search the items URL? And to answer your question, yes, I know for sure the item exists because I can see it when I use the filters.

Comment: If you are getting hits on some of the items, then the list is being crawled.  Re-indexing as you said above would be the remedy to catch anything that wasn't indexed in the last crawl.